# How can I get the maximum size I can resize an Excel worksheet?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have a C# add-in for Excel and I need to put the data on a worksheet.  I do it like so:

```
// Now build a string array of the results
string[,] resultArray = new string[objects.Length, length];

// Fill in the values
Excel.Range resultRange = worksheet.get_Range("A2").get_Resize(objects.Length, length);
resultRange.Value = resultArray;
```

I have left out some unimportant steps.  Basically, I am passed an array of objects, I get the type from the first one and use the properties to build a list of column names.  I put that in the row 1.  That is why I start the data in row 2.

The issue I ran across is that I had an Excel 97-2003 workbook (with max rows of around 65K row) and I tried to bring in 105K objects.  It choked on the resize.  I would like to check to see if my resize is even valid so I can tell the user, but I can't seem to find a "MaxRows" or similar property. Is there one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`worksheet.Rows.Count` will give you the maximum number of rows in a given worksheet. If you check this property before accessing a large number of rows you can make your program compatible with 2003, 2007, and take advantage of increased numbers of rows in all future versions of Excel.

Comment: I was thinking that deleting a row would reduce this count, but it seems like deleting a row adds a blank one on the end of the sheet.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, kind of unintuitive.
 - If you want the count of used rows you can go `worksheet.UsedRows.Count`.

Comment: Sorry, My edit took a little long. I meant to write:
Yeah, kind of unintuitive.
 -> If you want the count of used rows you can use `worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count`.
 -> If you want the last non-blank row you can use `worksheet.UsedRange.Row + worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count` (since usedRange doesn't always start on row 1)

Answer (score 1):

Here are the [hard limits for a worksheet in Excel 2003.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP005199291.aspx)  There is no programmatic way to exceed these limits, although you could start spreading data across multiple sheets or various other bits of trickery.

Excel 2010 has [expanded these limits significantly](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010342495.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP005199291). So an option might be to get your customer to upgrade as a part of the project.

Comment: I am using Excel 2007, but the limit is on the spreadsheet itself, so I wanted to warn the user first before getting tricky.  Really, I want them to open it up as a newer format and to have enough rows.